# Dependências Maven inseridas no Deployment Assembly somem após dar Maven -> Update Project

Tags: maven, dependências

Galera, minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Tenho por exemplo as seguintes pastas: (Cada projeto obviamente em sua pasta separada)

- Projeto1
- Projeto2
- ProjetoFinal

Quando vou gerar o build do ProjetoFinal eu adiciono em Deployment Assembly esses outros 2 projetos, até ai tudo bem, se eu rodo ele no tomcat vai de boa, porém quando eu dou um Maven -> Update Project e volto nessa parte do Deployment Assembly, os outros projetos que eu adicionei ali desaparecem da listagem, ai preciso adicionar novamente.

Alguém já passou por isso e imagina o que fazer para não desaparecem da listagem após o Update Project?

Tudo isso me atrapalha quando vou gerar o MVN CLEAN INSTALL, pois ele gera o war sem essas dependências.